# Refresh Button in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I'm trying to get the button shown in the top right corner of one of my pages to refresh WebView. Where in my code would I add text that would allow this to happen? [image]

```
    class CycleViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0196, green: 0.4, blue: 0.2902, alpha: 1.0)

        webView.isOpaque = false
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://jwelsh19.wixsite.com/countryday")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)

    }
}
```

Comment: Just add an UIButton on top of self.ivew and on top of webView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect this with the button in file Main storyboard

```
@IBAction func reload(_ sender: UIButton) {

    webView.reload()

}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Add an `UIButton` as your `view`'s subview, like the code bleow (adjust your refresh button frame by yourself)

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...
        webView.load(myRequest)
        let refreshButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        refreshButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        refreshButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(refreshButton)

    }

    @objc func refresh() {
    }
```

Comment: When I add this code the refresh button appears but does nothing when pressed